# I cannot identify this 2004 Volvo S60 part

Tags: electrical, volvo, part-identification

I'm selling my car and currently it sits and seeing as I'm not driving it every day I check on it every so often. When I checked today there was a small part that is connected to a tube leading into the engine block that had a small (about 2.5 inch by 3/8 inch) spring coming out of it. The spring is supposed to be held between the tube component and a plastic top component that had wires coming out of it on the other end. The plastic component with wires had snapped off most likely due to the force from constantly compressing the spring.

I apologize for the vagueness of the issue as my auto knowledge is extremely limited. If you have any idea what this could be it would be greatly appreciated if you could help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a picture please?

Comment: I cannot agree more with the picture idea ... definitely worth a thousand words in this case.

Comment: Difficult to answer without a photo. However do note that pretty much all Volvo parts have part numbers stamped on them. Googling the number will usually yield you the part's name.